# how to deal with OnChanges that requires an AfterViewInit

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am using D3 with Angular2, following the example [here](http://mean.expert/2016/09/17/angular-2-chart-component-revised/). My component is like:

```
@Component({
selector: 'example-component',
template: '<div #someElement></div>'
})
class exampleComponent implements OnChanges, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('someElement') someElement: any;
  @Input() someInput: any; //got from API in service provided by parent component

  htmlElement: any;
  selection: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.htmlElement = this.someElement.nativeElement;
    this.selection = D3.select(this.htmlElement);
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (!this.someInput) return;
    this.selection.append('svg');
// continue to build chart
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that the input can be ready before `ngAfterViewInit` is called. The `if` statement prevents the chart from being built before the input is ready but if it is ready before `ngAfterViewInit` then `this.selection` will be undefined when `ngOnChanges` is called. However one cannot add another condition for `this.selection` such as:

```
if (!this.someInput || !this.selection) return;
```

because then the chart will not be built at all in the case when the input is ready before `ngAfterViewInit` since `ngOnChanges` won't necessarily be called again after `ngAfterViewInit`.

Is there a best practice for a case like this? I realize that almost always the input will not be ready before `ngAfterViewInit` but it is possible. There are some similar concerns voiced [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7782) but it's not exactly the same.

Thanks in advance!

edit: after more experimentation it appears I can do

```
this.htmlElement = this.someElement.nativeElement;
this.selection = D3.select(this.htmlElement);
```

within `ngOnChanges`, even before `ngAfterViewInit`, which is surprising.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a function on the [SimpleChange](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/SimpleChange-class.html) object passed into ngChanges called **isFirstChange** which you can use to check if the change was before initialization (it will be true).

Comment: could you elaborate a little on how you might use that in this case? not sure how this would help me ensure both the view is initialized and the input is ready before proceeding with building a chart

Comment: I thought about it a bit more and came up doing nothing on the first change in `ngOnChanges` and building the first chart in `ngAfterViewInit`. Then on later changes the chart will be rebuilt. Maybe add this to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't get his to work. The problem I had was onChanges was firing before the reactive form was built. Ended up using ngAfterViewInit which works fine but doesn't have the inbuilt @input change detection

Comment: This is not an anwer to the question. isFirstChange happens to be before initialiszation, but if firstchange is false this doesnt mean the view is already init?! how is this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3):

So yeah, waiting for ViewInit is actually the only safe way to guarantee that e.g. Viewchilds are ready. This has nothing to do with isFirstChange. Wrong Lifecycle hook. isFirstChange = false maybe means the component is initialised, but OP asked for **AfterViewInit**

so my kinda cumbersome way of doing this is to create an observable. (of course you then have to unsubscibe on destroy maybe via an other observable but this is out of scope of this question.)

```
viewInit$ = new ReplaySubject();

ngOnChanges(){
    this.viewInit$.subscribe(()=>{
    // do something after View Init
    })
}

ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.viewInit$.next()
}
```